# Select customers who purchased BOTH this year and last -

Tags: sql

I am looking to find clients who purchased in period 31/08/2022 and if those same customers made a purchase in 31/08/2023.

The following columns

| Report Month |
| --- |
| unit_Revenue |
| cl_code |

i have tried to add a HAVING clause

```
Having 
Report_Month = '2022-08-31' or Report_Month = '2023-08-31'
and Sum(unit_Revenue) <> 0
and SUm(unit_Revenue) is not null
```

but does not return the desired results. It just returns all customers with invoices in both reporting period regardless whether new or not

there desired results should be as follows

'Should be present' column just to illustrate. That eg. client 3001 was not present in Aug-22 as no purchase value but client 101001, 115001 are present in both Aug-22 and Aug-23.

| cl_Code | Aug-22 | Aug-23 | Should be present |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3001 | 0 | 44.32 | No |
| 101001 | 42.94 | 90.68 | Yes |
| 115001 | 298 | 685 | Yes |
| 121921 | 18.24 | 0 | No |
| 123818 | 30.5 | 28 | Yes |
| 123819 | 1204.66 | 94.9 | Yes |
| 202004 | 67.1 | 0 | No |
| 202008 | 277.28 | 282.14 | Yes |
| 247008 | 16.8 | 0 | No |
| 247009 | 6.1 | 0 | No |
| 247012 | 214.6 | 196.75 | Yes |
| 288001 | 786.54 | 633.95 | Yes |
| 360008 | 160.24 | 0 | No |
| 360009 | 81.44 | 0 | No |
| JFM | 75.6 | 160.2 | Yes |

Comment: A SQL fragment is not very useful, some table schema/sample data is generally a useful addition to any SQL question; *Having* is an operation on aggregates you don't use it for filtering non-aggregated values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.CustomerID
FROM [table] t1
INNER JOIN [table] t2 ON t1.CustomerID = t2.CustomerID
    AND t2.Report_Month = '2023-08-31'
WHERE t1.Report_Month = '2022-08-31'
```

Comment: If i wanted to expand this a little bit to represent the table example how would i get it to display the revenue value of the months